# Ubuntu 14.04 sometimes hang after waking up

Tags: 14.04, drivers, crash, wakeup

I'm using Dell Optiplex 9020. And i install Ubuntu 14.04. But sometimes (not every time) after waking up my computer from suspend state. it will hang in the log in screen, i can't input anything, neither by mouse nor by keyboard.CTRL+ALT+F1 doesn't work either.

Is there anyway or command i can use to debug this problem?

Here is list by `sudo lshw|grep -iA6 vga`

```
            description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
--
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:48 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
```

Comment: Do you have drive/folder encryption? I am not sure if that would matter.

Comment: What happens if you press [Ctrl][Alt][F1]?  If you see something, try [Ctrl][Alt][F7].  Does that bring everything back?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `sudo lshw|grep -iA6 vga`

Comment: @ElderGeek I add the output to my original post

Comment: @ElderGeek Is there any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried http://askubuntu.com/questions/500911/ubuntu-14-04-not-recognizing-installed-intel-graphics-driver?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/500911/ubuntu-14-04-not-recognizing-installed-intel-graphics-driver?rq=1