# How to investigate/fix video corruption with intel Q43 onboard card

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, i915

I'm seeing a "venetian blind" effect on parts of my display after a fresh install of 15.10 64bit on a computer with Intel Q43 on board video.

Looks like some lines on some parts if the screen are not drawn/rendered.
For example, in nautilus the folder icons display ok, until I mouse over and then boom, venetian blind effect.

Was running 14.04 32bit previously and all was fine. Tried to go back to it and still have the same problem.
Dual booted into windows and didn't see the same effect.
Now I'm puzzled, is it a driver issue, or did the video hardware go bad when I did the install.
Any suggestions of where to go from here would be apreciated.

---

Update 1:
Installed 12.04.05 64bit and now have a working system.
Starting the update process to see what happens.

---

Update 2: Sucess, after leaving the system to update overnight, I have a working 14.04 64bit system on a Dell Optiplex 760 with E2200 cpu, Q43/45 graphics and 3 gigs ram.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you connect a different monitor?

Comment: Yes.  Two different monitors with two different cables.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/500911/ubuntu-14-04-not-recognizing-installed-intel-graphics-driver

Comment: Please keep us posted as to your results as your experience could help others with the same issue. Thank you!