# Ubuntu 16.04.1. LTS with dual monitor and integrated intel graphics

Tags: drivers, kernel, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I am a relatively inexperienced Ubuntu user: Some time ago I updated my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and after restarting the system, both my monitors (connected with DVI and HDMI ports) reported that the signal is lost. I was able to get the monitors working again booting with an old kernel.

However, the support for this kernel ended in August 2016 and I should probably find a solution that works with the latest kernels. Hence, I decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS but it lead to a situation where the monitors lost the signal when I installed/boot up the computer. I managed to get the signal back to my screens by setting the`nomodeset` option in the grub menu.

Unfortunately, now both monitors show the same view which is not what I would like to have.

Does anybody have an idea how to get a continuous dual display working again with the latest kernels? Here is the output of `lshw -c video`:

```
 *-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

and my kernel is now `4.4.0-45-generic` (the ubuntu release is 16.04.1 LTS). I have tried to reinstall the graphics drivers using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

But it doesn't seem to help me although I removed the `nomodeset` option temporarily in order to test the system.

*Do you have any ideas or suggestions?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 not recognizing installed Intel graphics driver](http://askubuntu.com/questions/500911/ubuntu-14-04-not-recognizing-installed-intel-graphics-driver)

Comment: @Fabby I overwrote the old 14.04 installation. It seems that the old installation doesn't affect the problem.

Comment: yup, follow the same answer as there...

Comment: @Fabby I installed the 64-bit version of Intel Graphics Update Tool for Ubuntu 16.04 from (https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads) and updated the driver. It actually updated and added some files but I still encounter the same problem. Without 'nomodeset' option the screens say just "no signal" after the grub menu.

Comment: File a bug report with Intel.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I have to file a bug report, but anyway the system log '/var/log/syslog' says that an error occurs when the system is starting: 'snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: failed to add i915 component master (-19)' at least in 'nomodeset' mode. However, I don't know if the error occurs because of 'nomodeset' option or not.

Comment: Put that in your bug report.