# dual monitor issue on ubuntu 16.04 laptop

Tags: 16.04

recently switched from win 8.1 to 16.04 , usually i would be using linux but this was the first time i had to use a laptop,  and it came with windows and i dint want to change any thing until circumstances forced me to.
So without (my mistake ) doing much research i downloaded a copy of 16.04 LTS and installed.

specs

DELL Inspiron-5520

cpu-Intel® Core™ i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4

gfx-intel HD / amd 7630m .. hybrid graphics

ram-4gb

It all went relatively well until i tried to use my secondary monitor, after looking through many ask-ubuntu  questions and other threads about the problem, it seemed support for the older amd cards was not too good , and none ended with any solutions for me.
The problem ..  when monitor is unplugged (from power), but the vga connector is plugged into the laptop it sees a unknown monitor in 
"System Settings->Displays, when power is on the screen refreshes and the options are gone. i have tried some solutions found on line but none work.
here are some of the pages.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

aparantly the amd-pro drivers don't seem to support 76XX,
..every thing seemed fine with the radeon driver currently installed.
 No errors.. and it reports both cards " appropriately  ".. i think

```
thenthusiast@thenthusiast-Inspiron-5520:~$ lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core          processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] [1002:6840] (rev ff)
```

[Dual monitor on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762236/dual-monitor-on-ubuntu-16-04)

[Ubuntu 16.04 Dual Monitor Not Working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855355/ubuntu-16-04-dual-monitor-not-working)

seems our problems are different

[Ubuntu 16.04.1. LTS with dual monitor and integrated intel graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845814/ubuntu-16-04-1-lts-with-dual-monitor-and-integrated-intel-graphics)

no solution here,

these were the closest but no luck. others were to complicated , since i have no experience with monitor issues. ( usually i had desktops before, the problems never showed up .. i think its the hybrid graphics ..)